# Adding a child to a Stackpanel in RowDetails from Code

Tags: c#, xaml, stackpanel, rowdetails

i have a DataGrid with a RowDetails Section. In the rowdetails i have a stackpanel. 
I want to add childs dynamically to this stackpanel with code.....but i can't access the panel from the code.

```
       <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <Border x:Name="Border_RowDetails" Margin="5" Padding="3" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="5">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel_Detail" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontSize="30" Text="Auftragsdetails:  " Margin="100, 0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>  
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```

I want to add Childs (Textblocks) to the Stackpanel "StackPanel_Detail" in the code behind file.

Background:

The DataGrid has an datatable as the itemssource. If i click on a row, the rowdetails show up and there i should show some more information from another datatable! The number of detailrows is not always the same. I don't really know how to do this with xaml and bindings as i am really new to wpf and xaml. All i could find was to just show other Columns in the rowdetails from the datagrid.itemssource. Therefore i wanted to calculate the number in the code behind and create Textblocks for every record.

Example:

**Datagrid**
Row1: Customer1    OrderID1
**Details:**
Row1: OrderID1 COILID1

**Datagrid**
Row2: Customer2    OrderID2
**Details:**
Row1: OrderID2 COILID1
Row2: OrderID2 COILID2

I would really appreciate every help. I am sorry for my bad english!

Regards,
Florian

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ItemsControl inside your RowDetailsTemplate (with a StackPanel as ItemsPanel), define its ItemsTemplate to be a DataTemplate that contains a TextBlock (or any complicated UI you want) and then DataBind the ItemsSource property of the ItemsControl to an ObservableCollection. A TextBlock will be then be generated for each item you add to your collection. MVVM to the rescue ;)
Note that you'd need to enhance your DataGrid Row ViewModels to each contain an ObservableCollection for the things you'd like to show inside its Details panel.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your fast answer. But could you please give me a short Example? I have never used ItemsControl and i first need to google ObservableCollection......sorry, i am ashamed!

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution in another board. i used a ContentPresenter and a "Content_Loaded"-Event and with that i coded the StackPanel and the TextBlocks in the Code.....not really the cleanest solution, i suppose, but it works!